# How can an "intermediate" promise be rejected in a chain of promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I understand that `promise 3` is rejected because it resolves to an already rejected promise (`promise 2`), but how does `promise 3` get to reject `promise 4`?, what is going on behind the scenes?

```
 Promise.resolve(6) // promise 1
 .then(function(data) {
    console.log('then 1:' + data);
    return Promise.reject(new Error('ups - rejected'));
 }) // promise 2
 .then(function (data) {
    console.log('then 2:' + data);
    return data + 1; 
 }) // promise 3
.then(function (data) {
    console.log('then 3:' + data);
    return data + 1; 
 }) // promise 4
 .catch(function(error) { // catch of promise 4
  console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252642/discussion-on-question-by-coder23-how-can-an-intermediate-promise-be-rejected); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it possible to use only a catch() at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75778431/why-is-it-possible-to-use-only-a-catch-at-the-end)

Answer (score 0):

Recall that each `then` in the chain defines a `Promise`, and they are processed in order. In the "happy case" there are no errors and the result of each `onFulfilled` handler is passed as an argument to the next `Promise`.

Similarly, if an error occurs – either by an explicit `Promise.reject` or a `throw` – then the error object is passed as an argument to the `onRejected` handler of the next `Promise`.

If an `onRejected` handler returns a value then it will be passed onto the next `onFulfilled` handler, i.e. the error is regarded as "taken care of"; if, however, it rejects or re-throws the error then **that will be passed to the next `onRejected` handler**.

The link you've provided clarifies that the default `onRejected` handler is `function ((x) => { throw x; })` – that is, if you don't define your own handler then any error from earlier in the chain is re-thrown. So, the default behaviour is that the error is just passed down the chain until it gets to the end.

Recall that `.catch(handler)` is just syntactic sugar for `.then(undefined, handler)`. There's nothing special about it being at the end – you can put `.catch(..)` handlers in the middle of the chain – but if some `Promise` in the chain throws an unhandled error then you see the familiar `Uncaught (in Promise)` message / error in the console.