# Why is it possible to use only a catch() at the end?

Tags: javascript, exception, asynchronous, error-handling, promise

I understand that `promise 3` is rejected because it resolves to an *already rejected promise* (`promise 2`), but how does `promise 3` get to reject `promise 4`?, **what is going on behind the scenes**?

```
Promise.resolve(6) // promise 1
 .then(function(data) {
    console.log('then 1:' + data);
    return Promise.reject(new Error('ups - rejected')); // Does it "jump" to the first catch() it finds?
 }) // promise 2 - this promise is resolved with a **rejected promise**
 .then(function (data) {
    console.log('then 2:' + data);
    return data + 1; 
 }) // promise 3
.then(function (data) {
    console.log('then 3:' + data);
    return data + 1; 
 }) // promise 4 
 .catch(function(error) { // catch of promise 4?
  console.log(error);
 });
```

Output:

```
then 1:6
index.js:57 Error: ups - rejected
    at index.js:46:27
```

Comment: What sort of answer are you looking for? Like, a link to the promise spec? Or the source code that the browser uses? Or just a high level description that rejecting a promise will also reject the next promise in the chain if it doesn't catch it?

Comment: What is the confusion here? You are creating and instantly rejecting a promise in the first `then` callback which is handled by the `catch` callback.

Comment: hi @damonholden that's the question, how does it "jump" from the `then()` handler that rejected to the last `catch()`?

Comment: hi @NicholasTower, the last one "high levvel description that reject a promise will also reject..."

Comment: That is just simply how the `catch` logic works in javascript, when an exception is thrown (in this case a rejected promise), the first `catch` in the callstack is what handles it. If there is no `catch` mechanism, then the whole call stack fails and an Error is thrown.

Comment: read the mdn documentation on the `Promise.prototype.catch()`method to understand how it works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: hi @Mulan you are wrong, `promise 2` (the promise returned by the first `then()`) resolves to an already rejected promise.

Comment: the first `then()` handler returns `Promise.reject(...` @Mulan

Comment: Well, now I agree @Mulan, so what's going on?

Comment: Please don't copy [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75776655/1048572), even if they were deleted for seemingly no reason

Comment: sorry @Bergi, I decided to copy it because I wanted a better approach. Could you give your answer now with the question better formulated, please. I would like to know your answer with details

Comment: I didn't catch all your comments on the question that was closed @Bergi. You would definitely get my +1

Answer (score 3):

Promises 3 and 4 aren't exactly skipped. As in [the documentation for `then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), the first argument to `then` provides what to do when the Promise is resolved, and the second argument provides what to do when the promise is rejected.

Both the `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` handlers mention that when the parameter is absent or not a function, the parameter is treated as an identity function:

> onFulfilled: "If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with an identity function (`(x) => x`) which simply passes the fulfillment value forward."

> onRejected: "If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with a thrower function (`(x) => { throw x; }`) which throws the rejection reason it received."

Because promise 2 is rejected, and because the `then` handler that creates promise 3 doesn't have a second argument, promise 3 just takes the same resolution as promise 2. Same with promise 4, because promise 3 is rejected and the `then` only has a first argument.

Because promise 4's resolution matches promise 3's and promise 2's, it approximates "skipping to the next catch" (or skipping to the next two-argument `then`), but only because you can't see promise 3 and promise 4 reject with the same outcome as promise 2. If you were to save them to a variable and inspect them later, you would see them rejected with the message you set in the first `then` block.

Comment: hi @Jeff Bowman thank you, but, where in the documentation does it say that if there is no 2nd argument in a `then()` it takes the same resolution as the previous promise?

Comment: I don't remember seeing that @Jeff Bowman

Comment: onRejected: "If it is not a function, it is internally replaced with a thrower function (`(x) => { throw x; }`) which throws the rejection reason it received." Because the parameters are optional, they are effectively undefined if you don't pass anything. I've edited quotes into the answer.